# Powershell: Select-String not maching as expected

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script that selects all the files in a directory that have "Sitecore.Social" in their filename.

Code:

```
$includeFolder = "C:\Sitecore_Installation\afhs72\Website\App_Config\Include\"
$temp = Get-ChildItem ($includeFolder + "*.config") | select-string -SimpleMatch "Sitecore.Social" | group path | select name
echo $temp
```

The link below is a screenshot of my powershell console when I run the script. I placed the code in "temp.ps1." When I run the script it doesn't display any files.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq2ug.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just print it to the console, you can use the code below:

```
$includeFolder = "C:\Sitecore_Installation\afhs72\Website\App_Config\Include\"
$temp = Get-ChildItem $includeFolder -name *sitecore.social*.config
echo $temp
```

This code will grab the child items from your $includefolder path and then look for a filename that has sitecore.social anywhere in the name AND it will also look for .config at the end.

To delete all the files with that string in the name, use a ri (remove-item)

```
ri C:\Sitecore_Installation\afhs72\Website\App_Config\Include\*sitecore.social*.config
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually am trying to use that code to delete every file that has "Sitecore.Social" in the filename. But I narrowed down the problem to the Select-String command, so I simplified my question to just focus on that. So I want to know why the Select-String command isn't filtering the files in a way I'm expecting.

Comment: Deleting a set of items is 1 line of code.  See my revised code above.

Comment: Your revised code is almost exactly what I ended up doing. However, I posted this question because I'm curious as to why the code I posted doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know.  Why are you using grouping when you just want to delete items? Why are you piping so much?  I'll let you figure out why your own code doesn't work since I already provided you with a solution.